# Testing Capacitor in PWM Circuit with Oscilloscope Calibration Signal

Tags: capacitor, pwm, dc-motor, oscilloscope

I'd like to measure the effect of a capacitor in a PWM circuit with an oscilloscope.  The capacitor is engaged on a switch connected to a DC motor.

Can I hook the motor up to the 1 kHz calibration output and ground to measure?

Will this adversely effect the oscilloscope?

Comment: There is a CircuitLab schematic button on the editor toolbar. Add in a schematic so we know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not.  I wouldn't think that the cal output on the oscilloscope is capable of providing enough current to drive the motor.  It probably also won't drive a large capacitative load, either.

I doubt it will hurt the scope -- but I don't see a very compelling reason to try, either.

Comment: Update: the scope couldn't drive the motor and the scope is fine.